# Sparse & Dense Polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, polytopes

I've been reading up on Bernstein's theorem for an algebraic geometry assignment and I've come across the terms "dense" and "sparse" in relation to the polynomials. However, I have been unable to find  a precise definition of what these terms mean in regards to polynomials and was wondering if anyone here might be able to help.

Comment: Bernstein proved many theorems. Which one are you talking about?

Comment: Worse, many Bernsteins proved many theorems...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Density vs sparsity for polynomials is an informal distinction: a (multivariate) polynomial is sparse if "most" of the coefficients of its monomials are zero, and dense otherwise.

If you have not found this reference yet,  [Sturmfels' book on solving polynomial equations](https://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf) has a chapter on Bernstein's theorem, and is in general very instructive.